# Is it possible to use the rgb color selection in the $mdThemingProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

i am developing a Firefox OS application with angularjs and angular-material; my problem is i would like to give my user the choice to customize their app so i used tree md-slider to select the red,green and blue color's the i used rgb with the sliders models in parameter to obtain a custom color.
Now i wonder if it is possible to do something like this:

```
myapp.config(['$mdThemingProvider',function($mdThemingProvider){
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('rgb(x,y,z)');
}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried this out? What is the result and why is that result not sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the default theme, you can only choose between :

- red
- pink
- purple
- deep-purple
- indigo
- blue
- light-blue
- cyan
- teal
- green
- light-green
- lime
- yellow
- amber
- orange
- deep-orange
- brown
- grey
- blue-grey

According to the doc : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/01_introduction

If you want custom colors, you'll need to define your own custom palette

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {
    '50': 'ffebee',
    '100': 'ffcdd2',
    '200': 'ef9a9a',
    '300': 'e57373',
    '400': 'ef5350',
    '500': 'f44336',
    '600': 'e53935',
    '700': 'd32f2f',
    '800': 'c62828',
    '900': 'b71c1c',
    'A100': 'ff8a80',
    'A200': 'ff5252',
    'A400': 'ff1744',
    'A700': 'd50000',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',    // whether, by default, text     (contrast)
                                    // on this palette should be dark or light
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
     '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
    'contrastLightColors': undefined    // could also specify this if default was 'dark'
  });
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName')
});
```

Se : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Comment: ok thanks i understand now! ... so i will first convert my r,g an b values to get the color Hex code the one i will then use to define a hue in my custom palette  .. thanks!!!.

Comment: No problem. Maybe you can directly use the rgb syntax, try it !